# iso-2022-jp charset on mono in linux (Amazon AMI)

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, mono, mime-types

I'm using SendGrid to receive emails via webhook. I'm receiving a well formed email with an HTML segment that is coming in as a charset iso-2022-jp

```
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-2022-jp\">
```

I see what the users have done. They are using outlook and have added special characters in their signature that is causing this. If I try to process this as UTF-8 I get garbled text as expected.

I'm using HTMLAgilityPack to load the email.

On Windows this this processes fine, but on Linux (Amazon AMI) I receive

> Encoding 50220 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled

Any idea how I can get this to process? I've read that I might be able to get the MS Core Fonts loaded somehow, but I haven't been able to get this to work on the Amazon AMI (http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the C#/mono/Linux combo for this and implemented a solution in PHP using [Sendgrid Parse](https://github.com/Ziggeo/php-sendgrid-parse)

```
 $parsed = new SendgridParse();
 $str = mb_convert_encoding($parsed->text, "UTF-8", $parsed->charsets->text);
```

Answer (score 0):

actually this fixed it in C#/mono

```
yum install mono-locale-extras
```